# How to resolve Entity Framework Unable to create a constant value of type in a query involving navigation properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my app's backend, I have an Entity called `User`, which has two navigation properties, `BlockedUsers` and `UsersThatBlockedUser`. As the names imply, those properties are a collection of users that our user have blocked, and users that blocked our users respectively. I am programming the messaging section of an app and I need to check if the sender or receiver of a message is in either one of those blocked lists, and if it is indeed, exclude that message from the result. Here is what I am trying:

```
IQueryable<Message> messages = db.Messages
        .Where(m => (m.SenderID == user.ID || m.Receiver.ID == user.ID) && m.DateSent > limitTime);
//no problem up to here.
messages = messages.Where(m => !user.BlockedUsers.Any(u => u.ID == m.SenderID))
        .Where(m => !user.BlockedUsers.Any(u => u.ID == m.ReceiverID))
        .Where(m => !user.UsersThatBlockedUser.Any(u => u.ID == m.SenderID))
        .Where(m => !user.UsersThatBlockedUser.Any(u => u.ID == m.ReceiverID));
```

When I execute the query, I am getting the infamous `Unable to create a constant value of type (my user type). Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.` error. I know the reason of this error: I am accessing the user object directly in a subquery, and if I could somehow had access to something like `db.Blocks.Where(BlockerID == senderID || BlockedID == senderID)`, the problem would go away as I'd be involving only with IDs. However, I don't have something called `db.Blocks`. In my SQL Server database (I'm using model-first EDMX designer), a table called `dbo.UserBlockedUser` is created, but is there any way to access that table in LINQ-to-Entities without involving a `User` entity directly, but only using its ID to query the blocks table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `Message` entity have navigation properties related to the Sender/Receiver? If so (seems like it does based on the SenderId/ReceiverId properties) you could do something like:

```
int userId = 10;

var messages = db.Messages
                 .Where(m => m.SenderId == userId || m.ReceiverId == userId)
                 .Where(m => !m.Sender.BlockedUsers.Any(u => u.Id == m.ReceiverId))
                 .Where(m => !m.Receiver.UsersThatBlockedUser.Any(u => u.Id == m.SenderId))
                 .Where(m => !m....
```

Didn't really check if those conditions made sense, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: It has, and I've tried your solution and it did work. But I have no idea why my query gives that error and your query doesn't. It again goes through the same navigation property.

Comment: The difference is what you're passing *into* the query as a parameter. In mine, I'm passing a primitive (`int`), while in yours, you are passing not only a reference type, but a query on that reference type (`user.BlockedUsers.Any()`).

Comment: I see.. So if I reference any non-primitive Entity object *within* the query itself, I'm all OK. But if I send an entity into the query, I'd get this error. Just checking if I got you correctly, am I right?

Comment: That is correct (more or less. not *every* case will work like that).